# Making a MOK-signed GRUB with extra modules

Tags: grub, uefi, secure-boot

I have a Wake-on-LAN situation where I'd like GRUB to make a network request to decide "should I boot Windows?", perhaps by `load_env (http,192.168.1.123)/grubenv` (so I can write that file just before waking the machine). Unfortunately the default Ubuntu-signed GRUB lacks modules such as `http` and `tftp`, and with Secure Boot on, it will refuse to load them from disk.

So I thought enrolling a MOK and signing a standalone version of GRUB would be a solution, but I'm getting a blue text-mode dialog that I believe comes from the shim, saying:

> **Verification failed: (0x1A) Security Violation**

There are subsequent "Shim UEFI key management" dialogs through which I can enroll the hash of `grubx64.efi` but weirdly having done that I still get the same result on the next boot, and the presented hash did not match a direct `sha256sum` of grubx64.efi or any other file in `/boot/efi`.

My MOK has "X509v3 Extended Key Usage: Code Signing, 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.6" i.e. **does not** have the "1.3.6.1.4.1.2312.16.1.2" ID like the distro-generated ones which would restrict it to kernel-module signing.

Here's what I did:

```
# cat >grub-initial.cfg <<EOF
search.fs_uuid [……/boot uuid……] root
set prefix=($root)/grub
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
EOF

# MODULES="tpm part_gpt lvm ext2 fat chain linux efifwsetup \
  efi_uga efi_gop efinet configfile normal gzio gfxterm ls cat \
  test echo http gfxterm_background png gfxterm_menu gfxmenu \
  sleep videoinfo gettext loadenv search luks password_pbkdf2 \
  extcmd terminal play linuxefi search_fs_uuid search_label \
  search_fs_file regexp reboot halt memdisk lsefi"

# grub-mkstandalone --compress=xz -O x86_64-efi -o grubx64.unsigned \
  --install-modules="$MODULES" --modules="$MODULES" --themes="" \
  --locales="en@quot" boot/grub/grub.cfg=grub-initial.cfg

# sbsign --key /etc/keys/MOK.priv --cert /etc/keys/MOK.pem \
  --output grubx64.efi grubx64.unsigned

# mokutil --test-key /etc/keys/MOK.der
/etc/keys/MOK.der is already enrolled

# sbverify --cert /etc/keys/MOK.pem /boot/efi/EFI/bifrost/grubx64.efi
Signature verification OK

# mkdir /boot/efi/EFI/bifrost
# cp grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/bifrost/
# cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/{shimx64.efi,mmx64.efi} /boot/efi/EFI/bifrost/

# efibootmgr -c -d /dev/nvme0n1p1 -L "bifrost auto select" -l "\EFI\bifrost\shimx64.efi"

# efibootmgr -v
[…]
Boot0001* bifrost auto select   HD(1,GPT,[……ESP uuid……],0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\BIFROST\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,[……ESP uuid……],0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)..BO
[…]
```

...and then reboot and manually choose the new boot entry, for now.

What I think is happening:

- When booting stock GRUB: `Boot0002` -> Ubuntu shim -> Ubuntu GRUB -> Linux or Windows
- When booting local GRUB: `Boot0001` -> copy of Ubuntu shim -> rejects my GRUB but I don't know why

Possible theories:

- I'm somehow booting some other shim somewhere?
- The copied Ubuntu shim is trying to boot something other than the `grubx64.efi` next to it?
- The copied Ubuntu shim is somehow expecting different keys from what `mokutil` is looking at?
- …or, most likely, I've misunderstood something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I needed to add [SBAT (Secure Boot Advanced Targeting)](https://github.com/rhboot/shim/blob/main/SBAT.md) which is basically a form of version information so that signatures on vulnerable software can be more efficiently revoked. As mentioned [on the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface/Secure_Boot#shim), shim version 15.3 onwards will not launch EFI binaries without a valid `.sbat` section. Both `grub-mkstandalone` that I used above and `grub-mkimage` have an option to add it:

`--sbat some-sbat-file.csv`

The first link above includes several example SBAT CSV files. I thought it best to use the information from the Ubuntu GRUB package I was using, which did not package this information as a separate file, but it can be extracted:

```
objcopy -O binary --only-section=.sbat grubx64.efi /dev/stdout
```

```
sbat,1,SBAT Version,sbat,1,https://github.com/rhboot/shim/blob/main/SBAT.md
grub,3,Free Software Foundation,grub,2.06,https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/
grub.ubuntu,1,Ubuntu,grub2,2.06-2ubuntu14.1,https://www.ubuntu.com/
```